# Can I only use background fetch in Xcode to download new content from the internet?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-fetch

I used a pdf kit to show the daily menu of a cafeteria as a pdf in my app. The menu changes everyday. I want to use background fetch to load the new content. Is it possible to get new content in the app by uploading a pdf of the new menu in my Xcode project or can I use background fetch only to download new content from an url?

Help is very appreciated. Don’t bother to ask if something was explained unclear.

Thank you,
JPJerry5

Comment: technically yes, you can use background URL session to download your content, but how will you find if there is a new content available to download? and how will you get URL to download that content? If you already have the url to download your new content, you can always start download task with URL background session and have your content downloaded. People often use silent notification to inform the availability of new content but usually approach changes from app to app. Without proper detail hard to help you further

Comment: If you are planning to hit an API to find availability of new data and then start download task to download it, then you must know data task can't be configured with background URL session (as far as I remember you can only configure download task) and you might not have enough to make these two calls serially (initially hit API find availability of Data and then start download task)